# on android P, how does a vendor bin load a shared library from platform?

Tags: android

On android O, my vendor bin ran without any error. But after the migration to android P, some errors occur even when compiling.
The errors was shown as blow:
"bin_name (native:vendor) should not link to libandroid_runtime(native:platform)."

So, how should vendor bin file do to load platform libs ?
Is this problem related to hidl? 
Is hidl a good choice?

Answer (score 0):

Song! I faced with same issue. In my case the next flag: LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS helps me (before it i used CURRENT_SDK_VERSION)